# How can I use native dates using mongodb field storage?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I currently have a setup with [mongodb](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb) as a backend and couldn't find a way to use native dates with [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module. Is there a way to specify a different field schema for mongodb / map the types to the native equivalent?

Comment: I'm not getting the "native" part, by "native" you mean default date styles???

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/bson-types/ -> Date object, rather than storing it as a string or int (if chosen timestamp)